# How can I start a activity from a parent class?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm pretty new to Android and Stack Overflow, so sorry if I'm missing something.

So I'm working on my first app. It needs to have a spinner as a menu, which opens up different activities. Instead of doing this for each of them, I've created a class called baseActivity that gets extended by all other classes. However, I can't seem to figure out what to use as the Context for the intent, since I'd like this to be a variable passed down from the child classes so that there doesn't have to be a function for each page.

This is my mainactivity at the moment:

```
public class MainActivity extends baseActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
private Spinner menuSpinner;
private static final String[]menuItems = {"Home", "Festival", "item 3"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    menuSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.menuSpinner);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,menuItems);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    menuSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    menuSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    String spinnerValue = menuSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    baseActivity loadActivity = new baseActivity();
    loadActivity.switchMenuValue(spinnerValue);
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

}
```

And here is the baseActivity:

```
public class baseActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

//Switch through all available pages, then make a intent to load the right one
public void switchMenuValue (String spinnerValue) {
    switch(spinnerValue) {
        case "Home":
            //Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            //startActivity(homeIntent);
            Log.d("CASE", "Home");
            break;
        case "Festival":
            Intent festivalIntent = new Intent(this, Festival.class);
            startActivity(festivalIntent);
            Log.d("CASE", "Festival");
            break;
    }
}
```

So its about this part:

```
Intent festivalIntent = new Intent(this, Festival.class);
            startActivity(festivalIntent);
```

'This' needs to be replaced, but I can't figure out by what.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it not working? Because it should since the first parameter of Intent only requires a context which you actually passed it down. Btw way too many downvotes for this question..

Comment: check my answer if any issue comment on answer

Comment: I would suggest to create a utility class Util containing a (static) switchMenuValue taking an additional context property.  Your onItemSelected can then be replaced with Util.switchMenuValue(spinnervalue, this)

Comment: Just calling "switchMenuValue(spinnerValue)" instead of loadActivity.switchMenuValue(spinnerValue); should also work. There is no need to create a separate loadActivity object since your mainActivity already inherits from baseActivity.

Comment: Didn't even realize that, I've changed it. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, class names preferably start with a capital (hence BaseActivity iso baseActivity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Here in this method

```
switchMenuValue (String spinnerValue,Activity act)
{
switch(spinnerValue) {
        case "Home":
            //Intent homeIntent = new Intent(act, MainActivity.class);
            //act.startActivity(homeIntent);
            Log.d("CASE", "Home");
            break;
        case "Festival":
            Intent festivalIntent = new Intent(act, Festival.class);
            act.startActivity(festivalIntent);
            Log.d("CASE", "Festival");
            break;
    }
}
```

### just try to pass you activity with spinnerValue

startActivity(festivalIntent);

change to

change this line act.startActivity(festivalIntent);

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! How would I pass the activity though ? If I just change it to 'loadActivity.switchMenuValue(spinnerValue, MainActivity);' It gives a 'Expression expected' on MainActivity.

Comment: act.startActivity(festivalIntent); try this one

Comment: switchMenuValue(spinnerValue, MainActivity.this)

Comment: pass like this switchMenuValue(spinnerValue, MainActivity.this)

Comment: and start activity like this act.startActivity(festivalIntent);

Comment: It works now, thanks man! That was alot simpler then what I was expecting.

Comment: welcome bro enjoy android

Comment: This might work but it is ugly: a separate Activity object (loadActivity) is created just to call a function on it.   There is no reason why the loadActivity object should be an Activity.  Cleaner solutions are 1) a separate Utility class or 2) a direct call to the MainActivity. switchMenuValue(spinnerValue) (no extra parameter needed) since MainActivity already inherits from baseActivity

Answer (score 1):

You can use one Activity as BaseActivity and can use Fragments instead of using multiple Activities.

you can use following code to use fragments

> ```
>  public void changeFragment(Fragment nextFragment, boolean addToBackstack) {
>     int containerId = R.id.content_frame;
>
>     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
>     final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager
>             .beginTransaction();
>     transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right,
>             R.anim.exit_to_left);
>     if (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(containerId) != null) {
>         fragmentName = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(containerId);
>     }
>
>     transaction.replace(containerId, nextFragment);
>     transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
>     if (addToBackstack == true) {
>         transaction.addToBackStack(fragmentName.getClass().getName());
>     }
>     currentFragment = nextFragment.getClass().toString();
>     transaction.commit();
> }
> ```

Happy Coding..